# How do I clear ARP cache in macOS Catalina (10.15.7)?

Tags: macos, arp

I am trying to clear ARP cache on my mac.

`arp -a` : displays all the addresses
`ip -s -s neigh flush all` gives me `Option "-s" is unknown, try "ip -help"` in macOS Catalina (10.15.7).

Can someone tell me if there is work around or what am I doing wrong here.

Comment: `ip` is not a standard macOS command. Did you install it from somewhere else (e.g. homebrew)?

Answer (score 0):

The Mac does not have an *ip* command, this is for linux. MacOS is based on BSD, which has an entirely different network stack. Use this:

##### View the ARP cache

```
arp -a
```

##### Delete a single entry (1.1.1.1)

```
sudo arp -d 1.1.1.1
```

##### Flush the whole ARP cache

```
sudo arp -a -d
```